# Cron Error Magento 2: Please set a website ID

Tags: magento2.3, error, magento-cron, cronjobs

I have custom cron, which initially had an error:

> Please set a website ID.

I got rid of this issue by doing below:

```
$this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($store_id, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);

//my code

$this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

Then after some time on the server, I had an error:

> Process went away at 2020-02-09 12:19:06 (supposed time)

This issue was solved by simply removing the above emulation code which I added to solve the

> Please set a website ID.

error and it was working again fine for some time.

Now I am again getting the same error

> Please set a website ID.

Please tell me what is actually wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that `$store_id` is  right.

> The store id which you provide is not right. that why it is happening.